# Adding course to DB (LINQ)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, record

I am trying to add a new record to a table i my database.  The code I have adds the record to the table but also throws an exception "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_COURSE_TAKEN'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.COURSE_TAKEN'. The duplicate key value is (000160228, HIS 155).".  Why is it trying to add the record twice?  I know for 100% certainty that there is no existing record already present before I try to add it.  Below is my code for adding the record:

```
using (KuPlanEntities db = new KuPlanEntities())
            {
                var courseTake = new COURSE_TAKEN();
                courseTake.Id = "000160228";
                courseTake.courseAbNum = courseAbNum;
                courseTake.status = status;
                courseTake.grade = grade;
                db.COURSE_TAKEN.Add(courseTake);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: have you tried to debug the code to see if you are accidentally calling it twice?

Comment: In the first line add `bool exists = db.COURSE_TAKEN.Any(c => c.ID == "000160228");` to check that it does not exist

Comment: Put a break point and see if the code is called twice by some logical error.